# Conflicting Assembly References

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, orchardcms

I was downloading the master branch of the Orchard CMS.
After compliation there was a Warning regarding Orchard.Workflows.

I tried this tool: https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy

And the result is that I have a lot of conflictis.

So I really assume I am doing something wrong here. Is there something I am missing?

[image]

I get these results when I run AsmSpy agains the Release folder after compilation.

This is the original warning I want to get rid off:

Project: Orchard.Workflows

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Description: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved. These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Comment: Is the warning preventing the application from working?

Comment: Actually it seemed that the ClickToBuild.bat did not work. But I have got to re-check this. But the application was working when I compiled it in VS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will always get some reference warnings, at least most of the time as we are using a very broad set of open source softwares. For instance ASP.NET Web API is still linking to a specific version of Json.NET 4.5 and we are using Json.NET 6.0. We are setting assembly redirections to force which version to use.

In your example you can also see that NHibernate was compiled against CLR 2.0 for instance. Only the next version will be using CLR 4.0.

So the rule is that as long as it works, ignore the warnings. However it's interesting to take a look at them from time to time as it might be something we can fix. As explained in the warning, enable the verbose build log and the sources for these conflicting versions will be explained.

**Update**: I fixed the warning !

Comment: So it means that everyone building the master branch has this warning regarding Orchard.Workflows? As a former embedded c developer I am always concerned about warning. But it seems to be different in the managed code world as it seems.

Comment: I just updated my answer to mention I have fixed it. My comments still apply for Visual Studio warnings.